# python unittest mock a method of an imported class

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I am trying to mock a method of an object. It seems like I do not understand how to do it.

My class:

`my_class.py`

```
from astroquery.astrometry_net import AstrometryNet


class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, file):
        self.file = file

    def solve(self, apikey):
        ast = AstrometryNet()
        ast.api_key = apikey
        wcs_header = ast.solve_from_image(self.file, force_image_upload=True)
        return wcs_header
```

unit test

`test_myclass.py`

```
import unittest
from my_class import MyClass

class TestMyClass(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.SAMPLE = MyClass("the_file")

        self.APIKEY = "SOME_KEY"

    def test_solve(self):
        solved = self.SAMPLE.solve(self.APIKEY)
        self.assertEqual(solved, "some_value")
```

I tied multiple ways using patch, MagicMock, and mock. The closest I came to the solution was when `AstrometryNet` complained that it cannot connect to the server.

here the code:

```
class TestMyClass(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.SAMPLE = MyClass("the_file")

        self.APIKEY = "SOME_KEY"

    def test_solve(self):
        m = MagicMock()
        m.solve= Mock(return_value="Mocked Value")
        with patch('my_class.MyClass', return_value=m) as p:
            solved = self.SAMPLE.solve("asd")
```

I forgot to ask. How do we make sure the method in question raises an exception?

Comment: Have you tried with: `with patch.object(self.SAMPLE, 'solve') as mock_solve`? In this way you substitute (mock) the method `solve()` with the Mock object `mock_solve`.